# Nonlinear least squares curve fitting using SQL Server or .NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, least-squares, nonlinear-functions

I'm reconstructing a `MATLAB` based application to web based. At a specific point (of the MATLAB's implementation), the user uploads a set of data consisting of 2 columns (x, y) which is depicted as dots using a scatter plot. Subsequently a "best fitted" curve which passes through the points is estimated and designed using MATLAB's build-in `non-linear least squares` function and the `trust-region` optimization algorithm.

Is there any way to implement this function to either SQL Server or in .NET code respectively? I am looking for any simple example to fully understand the algorithm (step-by-step) but it is hard for me to find any pseudocode or implementation in another language concerning non-linear regression. I have only found some solutions about linear fitting but in my case only the specific algorithm does the work because I have to produce the same results (as the MATLAB's application does).

Comment: After reviewing the formal, step-by-step description of the algoritm here provided by mathworks athttps://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html, it seems unlikely you will find an exact algorithm implementation that matches exactly what they have done in every detail - their implementation is most thorough and detailed with several special cases.  If the standard Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear solver gives the same results for your problem space, that code is much easier to find using web searches.

Comment: So any idea then, how to implement the best fitting curve depending on the x,y values using web technologies?

Comment: On Github using Python 3: https://github.com/zunzun/zunzunsite3/ - I'm the author.  From the project description:"A Django site in Python 3 for curve fitting 2D and 3D data that can output source code in several computing languages and run a genetic algorithm for initial parameter estimation. Includes orthogonal distance and relative error regressions. Generates PDF files and surface animations."  It has parallel processor "function finding" as well.  BSD license, and comes with hundreds of named equations and user-defined functions.

Comment: Seems cool but I am using MS-SQL and VB.NET technologies in my project (as it is mentioned in the title), so I am looking for a very specific solution.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2016: [Using R Code in Transact-SQL (SQL Server R Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591996.aspx) and [Demonstration of nls function](http://robinlovelace.net/2013/10/23/nls-demonstation.html). I haven't tried it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I implemented my solution in such a way, namely using R code through SQL Server 2016. I will upload a simple example of this approach soon. Now I am trying to find a hosting provider/company with the specific infrastracture. Any suggestions on that matter?